# Google Map SDK Swift, Zooming in and out like Uber's Map

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am trying to implement the Google Map SDK, and so far I have implemented a marker. I made the marker in a way that it follows as it is located in the center when I move the camera position.

The problem is that I can't zoom in and out while the marker's location is not changing. I would like to make the zooming experience like Uber in which the location does not change.. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this line [`allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings#overview) to your GMSMapview. It controls whether rotate and zoom gestures can be performed off-center and scrolled around. The default value of this is YES.

```
mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = false // NO for obj-c and false for swift
```

So by setting it by NO/false, you can now perform zooming while the marker location is not moving. For more information, check this [thread](http://www.ceus-now.com/zoom-without-changing-camera-center/).

Comment: Thank you so much.. you literally saved my life because I have been dealing with this problem for 3 hours.

Comment: Hello there. I wonder if you can help me with my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450670/moving-camera-in-google-maps